# Flutter BLoC architecture List and Detail screens

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

Architecture question on Bloc and Flutter.
I have a List Screen with a Listview populated with `StreamBuilder`.
On Item tap, it opens a Detail Screen where the user can edit the values of that item.
That change has to be propagated to the List Screen Bloc, so that when Detail Screen is dismissed, the change is already reflected on the list.

I was thinking on sharing the same Bloc but thought there might be a better way.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Alaueraf did you find the good solution for this? I have the same challenge and still have no a good vision.

Comment: @BambinoUA you can either pass the bloc, or use a Repository shared by both BlocA and BlocB.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I was working on my blog post regarding BLoC. I found out that the best solution is to have one BLoC attached to one screen. These BLoCs can communicate with each other, and get each other states. You can follow [my article](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/flutter-bloc) if you are still interested in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

U have many options, but the simplest is share the bloc with a Provider or Singleton

Answer (score 0):

We can use another stream for the detailed screen with respect to the list stream

Comment: Thanks for your answer, on rx, what do you mean by "with respect to"?